# jmeter how make all http request sampler in one thread group run concurrently?

Tags: jmeter

i have one thread group in jmeter and in it i create several http request sampler and when i run this thread group,i found that seems all these http request executed one by one from "view rults tree". So i what to know how can all these http request run concurrently?

My thread group and test plan only need to be executed once one minute,and i use a bat file to run ,command is :

```
 call C:\apachejmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\apachejmeter\app1.jmx -l d:\restmon\restmon.jtl
```

your prompt reply would be deeply appreciated!!!!!

Comment: did you add any ramp-up time?

Answer (score 1):

This is how JMeter works:

1. JMeter creates threads defined in Thread Group
2. Threads start executing samplers upside down (default) or according to logic controllers
3. When there are no samplers to execute and no loops to iterate thread is being shut down

There are several ways to control concurrency:

- Playing with ramp-up and run time
- Using [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) which is capable of pausing threads until required number is reached and releases them at the same moment of time
- Switching to [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides some extra options to control the load scenario.

I think that Synchronizing Timer is what you're looking for.